# QT creator with mingw, glew linking errors

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator, glew

I've been trying for around 3/4 days to link glew with qt creator, but I´m unable to.
I've tried with msvc and mingw 64 & 32 bits.
Right now I´m using mingw 32 bits, and also a 32bits glew compiled with mingw.

This is the code in my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui opengl

CONFIG += c++11

INCLUDEPATH += C:/lib/glew-gcc-debug-1.10.0-win32/include/GL

LIBS += -lglew32.dll -LC:/lib/glew-gcc-debug-1.10.0-win32/bin -LC:/lib/glew-gcc-debug-1.10.0-win32/lib


TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += \
    glslprogram.cpp \
    glutils.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainview.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    sceneLine.cpp \
    dialog.cpp \
    viewpositiondialog.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    glslprogram.h \
    glutils.h \
    mainview.h \
    scene.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    sceneLine.h \
    dialog.h \
    viewpositiondialog.h

FORMS += \
    dialog.ui \
    viewpositiondialog.ui

OTHER_FILES += \
    shader/scenebasic2.dat
```

and this is is the output:

```
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\Test.exe object_script.Test.Debug  -lmingw32 -LC:/Qt/Qt5.5.0/5.5/mingw492_32/lib -lqtmaind -lshell32 -lglew32.dll -LC:/lib/glew-gcc-debug-1.10.0-win32/bin -LC:/lib/glew-gcc-debug-1.10.0-win32/lib -lQt5OpenGLd -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored 
./debug\glutils.o: In function `ZN7GLUtils19checkForOpenGLErrorEv':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:34: undefined reference to `glGetError@0'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:39: undefined reference to `glGetError@0'
Makefile.Debug:112: recipe for target 'debug\Test.exe' failed
./debug\glutils.o: In function `ZN7GLUtils10dumpGLInfoEb':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:46: undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:47: undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:48: undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:49: undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:52: undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:53: undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/glutils.cpp:63: undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
./debug\mainview.o: In function `ZN8MainView12initializeGLEv':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/mainview.cpp:113: undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
./debug\sceneLine.o: In function `ZN9SceneLine9initSceneEv':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:279: undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:280: undefined reference to `glEnable@4'
./debug\sceneLine.o: In function `ZN9SceneLine6renderEPf':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:325: undefined reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:336: undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
./debug\sceneLine.o: In function `ZN9SceneLine6renderEdPf':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:350: undefined reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:360: undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
./debug\sceneLine.o: In function `ZN9SceneLine6renderEddddddPf':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:393: undefined reference to `glClear@4'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:417: undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:421: undefined reference to `glDrawArrays@12'
./debug\sceneLine.o: In function `ZN9SceneLine6resizeEii':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/sceneLine.cpp:441: undefined reference to `glViewport@16'
./debug\sceneLine.o: In function `ZN5SceneC2Ev':
C:\Development\test\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../Test/scene.h:4: undefined reference to `vtable for Scene'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Development/test/build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Your link command line looks suspect; in particular, the absence of `-mwindows`, and the order in which libraries are specified. Why do you specify `-lshell32` and `-lmingw32`? These are default libraries; the compiler driver should be left to specify them for itself. Why do you specify `-lglew32.dll`? Surely it should be `-lglew32`, (unless your DLL is _really_ called `glew32.dll.dll`).

Comment: I do not specified shell or mingw libraries, that's just the output. Since the library is glew32.dll.a (compiled with mingw) you need to put the ".dll" in order to link it.

Comment: "_I do not specified shell or mingw libraries, that's just the output._". Doesn't mean it's correct -- it isn't, (although this _may_ not be critical; OTOH, order of libraries _is_).

Comment: "_Since the library is glew32.dll.a (compiled with mingw) you need to put the ".dll" in order to link it._" Wrong! Suggest you read [the appropriate manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32); you are telling it to look for `libglew32.dll.dll.a`, `glew32.dll.dll.a`, `libglew32.dll.a` (which it may just find, fortuitously, but incorrectly, because that should be a static library, not a dll import library), `glew32.lib`, `libglew32.dll`, and then `glew32.dll`, in precisely this search order.

Comment: Correction to my last comment: the last three items in _your_ specified search list, as expanded from `-lglew32.dll`, should read `glew32.dll.lib`, `libglew32.dll.dll`, and `glew32.dll.dll`, respectively.